# Variable in name of file

Tags: php

```
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if( isset($_POST['subm_btn']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
}

function getClickCount() {
    return (int) file_get_contents("$username.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount() {
    $count = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("$username.txt", $count);
}
```

Script should count clicks and write in file with name "username.txt", but it create file .txt

Comment: Are you sure that `$username` isn't empty?

Comment: @Joe I try echo, it is not empty

Comment: It's been a long time since I did PHP, but will the variable `$username` be evaluated in this case ?? shouldn't it be : `return (int)file_get_contents($username.".txt");` or `file_put_contents($username.".txt", $count);` ; I seem to recall it will only be avaluated in a string that you echo...but I may be wrong.

Comment: did you try $username.".txt" ?

Comment: @raghuveer999 Yes, same result

Comment: $username must be empty or null if the output is ".txt".

Comment: @Bartdude, yes PHP allows standard variables in quotes (excluding single quotes).  You can also use "{$variable}txt" if there wasn't a separator like the period is "$variable.txt".  However, most developers still use the concatenation with a period.

Comment: Thanks for clarification guys, good to know. And I indeed always prefered the "concatenation" way in the good old times, cause I thought it was much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the **global** keyword.

```
function getClickCount(){
     global $username;
     //remaining code here    
}
```

Do the same thing for `incrementClickCount()` also.

This is because the variable `$username` in both the functions has a local scope i.e it refers to a variable local to that function and since it hasn't been assigned any value (within the function), it has a default value of `null`.

The `global` keyword makes its scope global, it refers to the `$username` declared above both the functions.For more information look 
[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: You're welcome :) . Also please mark it as the correct answer as it will be helpful for others.